# MYSQL JOIN query to group user skills for conditional count

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I am struggling to find the logic for a JOIN query with GROUP BY.

I have 3 tables.

```
 1. tbl_users
 2. tbl_event_orders
 3.tbl_event_signature ( For saving signatures on completed events)
```

tbl_users

```
id    name     skill
---------------------------
1     user1     A
2     user2     B
3     user3     A
4     user4     A
```

tbl_orders

```
id     user_id    item_id    price
------------------------------------
1          1               1                 100
2          2               1                 100
3          3               1                 100
4          4               1                 100
```

tbl_signature

```
id     item_id      user_id       signature
----------------------------------------------
1               1                 1                 xxxxxxxx...
1               1                 3                 NULL
1               1                 4                 xxxxxxxx...
```

I need the event details from item id.
For example for item with  id 1, I need the following result.

```
skill         total_count     attended_users_count          amount
A                3               2                          300
B                1               0                          100
```

> skill - skill from user table.
>
> total_count  - total count of orders from that partical skill.
>
> attended_users_count   -  total count of orders from that partical skill + this should have an entry and a NOT NULL value  in tbl_signature table.
>
> amount   -  sum of price(total_count)

I have the following query for getting users with skills and total count.

```
SELECT 
U.skill as skill, 
count(U.skill) as total_count,
sum( O.price ) as amount
FROM  tbl_users U
INNER JOIN  tbl_orders O
ON U.id = O.user_id
WHERE O.item_id = 1
GROUP BY U.skill
```

but when dealing with attended users count, I am getting unexpected results.
I have tried with the following query,

```
SELECT 
U.skill as skill, 
count(U.skill) as total_count,
count( S.signature ) as attended_users_count,
sum( O.price ) as amount
FROM  tbl_users U
INNER JOIN  tbl_orders O
ON U.id = O.user_id
LEFT JOIN  tbl_signature S
ON  O.item_id = S.item_id
WHERE O.item_id = 1
GROUP BY U.skill
```

Is there any way to get this in a single query?

Comment: What are the expected results and what results do you get?

Comment: `count( S.signature ) as attended_users_count,` counts on a `LEFT JOIN  tbl_signature S` which can have `NULL` values.. `COUNT(*)` does not count `NULL` values.  So try `COUNT(CASE WHEN S.signature IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS attended_users_count`  first to see if you get the results you need..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I have added the expect result in the question. When using COUNT(CASE WHEN S.signature IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS attended_users_count  I am getting attended_users_count as 9 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want. It `JOIN`s `tbl_orders` to `tbl_users`, and then `LEFT JOIN`s to `tbl_signature`. Rows of `tbl_signature` which don't match, or which don't have a signature, will not get included in the count for that order:

```
SELECT u.skill,
       COUNT(o.id) AS total_count,
       COUNT(s.signature) AS attended_users_count,
       SUM(o.price) AS amount
FROM tbl_orders o
JOIN tbl_users u ON u.id = o.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_signature s ON s.item_id = o.item_id AND s.user_id = u.id
WHERE o.item_id = 1
GROUP BY u.skill
```

Output:

```
skill   total_count attended_users_count    amount
A       3           2                       300
B       1           0                       100
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2tfc7n3wa9asHqGhrXxbR9/0)

Comment: Site note: @Jobz if you need to change this query in the future and you need to filter information from the `tbl_signature s` table/alias don't put the condition in the `WHERE` like so `WHERE o.item_id = 1 AND s.columns = 1` this will give you invalid results (INNER JOIN's instead), the non `NOT IS NULL` filter conditions like `=` on the `LEFT JOIN` table/alias needs to be added with a `AND` in the `ON` clause... Very easy to go wrong with this.